# How to add mattooltip by custom directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am creating a custom directive called TooltipDirective whihc is going to add matTooltip to every host element, code is like below

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective implements OnInit
{
    @Input() tooltip: string;
    constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.hostElement.nativeElement, 'matTooltip', this.tooltip);
    }
}
```

In my html I have two elements to compare the result

```
<i class="material-icons" tooltip="Test Tooltip">reply_all</i>
<i class="material-icons" matTooltip="Test Tooltip">reply_all</i>
```

in the result html `tooltip` and `mattooltip` attributes are added but it doesn't show the tooltip.

and rendered html is like below

```
<i _ngcontent-c10="" class="material-icons" tooltip="Test Tooltip" mattooltip="Test Tooltip" ng-reflect-tooltip="Test Tooltip">reply_all</i>
<i _ngcontent-c10="" class="material-icons" mattooltip="Test Tooltip" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-1" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Test Tooltip">reply_all</i>
```

I tried adding other extra attributes but still doesn't work.

Comment: mattooltip is already a directive, why can't you use it? https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api

Comment: In a nutshell this will not work because adding an attribute to an element is not the same thing as creating and attaching a directive to an element.

Comment: mattooltip attribute didn't work, but matTooltip attribute worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other answer and comments are correct, btw finally I made it like this and it's working

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Inject, Input, NgZone, Optional, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import
{
    MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY,
    MatTooltip,
    MatTooltipDefaultOptions
} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { AriaDescriber, FocusMonitor } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { Directionality } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { Overlay, ScrollDispatcher } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { Platform } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/platform';

@Directive({
    selector: '[tooltip]',
    exportAs: 'tooltip'
})
export class TooltipDirective extends MatTooltip
{
    @Input()
    get tooltip()
    {
        return this.message;
    }
    set tooltip(value: string)
    {
        this.message = value;
    }

    constructor(
        _overlay: Overlay,
        _elementRef: ElementRef,
        _scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,
        _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        _ngZone: NgZone,
        _platform: Platform,
        _ariaDescriber: AriaDescriber,
        _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
        @Inject(MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY) _scrollStrategy: any,
        @Optional() _dir: Directionality,
        @Optional() @Inject(MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
        _defaultOptions: MatTooltipDefaultOptions)
    {
        super(
            _overlay,
            _elementRef,
            _scrollDispatcher,
            _viewContainerRef,
            _ngZone,
            _platform,
            _ariaDescriber,
            _focusMonitor,
            _scrollStrategy,
            _dir,
            _defaultOptions
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks your example helped me, do you know how to change the default UI of tooltip, i want to add specific type of tooltip with a complex data not just string and that complex data will be binded in tooltip UI

Comment: Is there any solution for this behavior now with Angular Version 13. It dont seem to work anymore. is there any stackblitz link for the same.

Comment: Good question, is it working for Angular13? Is it possible to have an example on stackblitz ? Thank in advance ;)

Comment: @NicoESIEA question and answer was back in 2018, I think it was Angular 5 or 6

Comment: Question from @TusharMaheshwari was not answer... And for now I'm using mtxTooltip library, but maybe there is another solution using directly material ^^

Comment: from "@ng-matero/extensions": "^13.3.0"

Comment: There should be one more parameter in the super method, _document which is of type any in the class, I am not sure how it is working at your end, maybe the version is old one.

Once you hover on the tooltip and scroll there, you'll get and error saying

this._document.elementFromPoint is not a function

if you keep it as any, it will through an error. So, what type should we assign to that

Comment: @KaranPatokar this answer was written in 2018, I think it was Angular 5 in that time, in the newer version there the base class might need more or less parameters

Answer (score 8):

This works for me. In my case I needed to have some checks before displaing the tooltip on 'mouseover' event.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTooltip } from '@angular/material/tooltip';


@Directive({
    selector: '[customTooltip]',
    providers: [MatTooltip]
})
export class CustomTooltipDirective {
    @Input() tooltipText: string;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private tooltip: MatTooltip) {}

    @HostListener('mouseover') mouseover() {
            this.tooltip.message = this.tooltipText;
            this.tooltip.show();
    }
    @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave() {
            this.tooltip.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this one worked for me

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import{ MatTooltip } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appTooltip]',
    exportAs: 'appTooltip',
})
export class SharedUiTooltipDirective extends MatTooltip {

  @Input() appTooltip!: string

  override get message(): string {
      return this.appTooltip
  }
}
```

Then if you want override other things like disabled state :

```
@Input() isDisabled?: boolean

  override get disabled(): boolean {
    return this.isDisabled ?? false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular 15 (mentioned by @PotatoesMaster), the correct approach would be to use the [Directive Composition API](https://angular.io/guide/%E2%80%A6) instead of inheritance.

```
@Directive({
  selector: `[myTooltip]`,
  standalone: true,
  hostDirectives: [MatTooltip]
})
export class MyTooltipDirective {
  constructor(private tooltip: MatTooltip) {
    // Use DI for accessing the MatTooltip
    this.tooltip.message = 'Test Tooltip';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it in Angular. Keep an eye on [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785), so if maybe Angular guys will do it in case they start doing meaningful work.

Your other option is to create a dynamic component for this situtation which sucks for this kind of little thing. I'm not sure but it may break your AOT.

Comment: Directive composition API is coming to Angular 15 (release expected in November 2022) : https://angular.io/guide/roadmap#support-adding-directives-to-host-elements

Answer (score 0):

For the people who want to do this programmatically with plain JS:

```
  const buttonWithTooltip = document.createElement('button');
  buttonWithTooltip.textContent = 'My Tooltip Button';
  buttonWithTooltip.setAttribute('matTooltip', 'Tooltip Text Here');
  buttonWithTooltip.classList.add('mat-button', 'mat-tooltip');
  this.parentElementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(buttonWithSpan);
```