# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "amgTooltip"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I've made a directive which inherits from MatTooltip from Angular Material. I know this is possible from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272037/how-to-add-mattooltip-by-custom-directive-in-angular).
However, when I try to use it, I get the following error:

`There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "amgTooltip"`

This is the code in the directive, which contains a constructor which calls the constructor on super. It's not shown in the code below for conciseness.

As you can see, the Directive configuration object has an exportAs property of 'amgTooltip'.

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[amgTooltip]',
  exportAs: 'amgTooltip'
})
export class AmgTooltipDirective extends MatTooltip {

    constructor(...) {...}

}
```

This directive is registered into a directives module class:

```ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AmgTooltipDirective} from './amg-tooltip';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [AmgTooltipDirective],
  exports: [AmgTooltipDirective]
})
export class DirectivesModule {

}
```

This module is referenced by our feature module in the `imports` section:

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...,
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

From there, we reference `amgTooltip` exactly the same way as we would reference `matTooltip`:

```html
<mat-icon 
    #icoTooltip="amgTooltip" 
    matTooltip="Tooltip Text"
    matTooltipPosition="after">
        icon_name
</mat-icon>
```

However, this is where we get the error and can go no further. I can try to create a Plunkr if requested, but I currently don't have one.

What silly mistake have I made? Thanks

Comment: shouldn't this  #icoTooltip="amgTooltip"  be applied to <... amgTooltip ...>?

Comment: No, remember all I am trying to do is extend matTooltip.
`<mat-icon #icoTooltip="matTooltip" ...>` is valid and we have been using this previously.

Comment: angular cannot understand #icoTooltip="amgTooltip" from mat-icon since mat-icon does not have amgTooltip, so what is your point?

Comment: @ABOS - my apologies, I thought you wrote `<amgTooltip>` I have added the `amgTooltip` attribute to the `<mat-icon ...>` element and the error has gone. Thank you.

Comment: Virtual Anomaly, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `amgTooltip` to the `mat-icon` element works.

```html
<mat-icon 
    amgTooltip
    #icoTooltip="amgTooltip" 
    matTooltip="Tooltip Text"
    matTooltipPosition="after">
        icon_name
</mat-icon>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "mdbTable"  any luck ?  @Virtual Anomaly